# Adicionar o titulo do formulário num campo hidden (Contact Form 7 WP Plugin)

Tags: wordpress, plugin-wordpress

Boa tarde,

É possível adicionar, num campo hidden, o titulo do formulário do plugin Contact Form 7 (Wordpress)

Este é o shortcut usado plo plugin:

[contact-form-7 id="86" title="**Titulo do Contacto**"]

Isto porque tenho uma página com algumas opções que abrem numa janela modal, e nessa janela existe um formulário. consegui que ao abrir, e com java script, me alterasse o URL da página com um id mas o plugin "Contact Form 7 Dynamic Text Extension" apenas vai buscar esses parâmetros se este existir ao abrir a página e não se eu o alterar depois de a página estar carregada.

EDIÇÃO:

Entretanto já consegui ter acesso ao nome do formulário com este script:

```
// add sortcut [hidden]
wpcf7_add_shortcode('hidden', 'wpcf7_sourceurl_shortcode_handler', true);

//função para ir buscar o titulo do formulário
function wpcf7_sourceurl_shortcode_handler() {

$name = "titulo_curso";
$form = wpcf7_get_current_contact_form(); // info sobre o formulário
echo '<pre>' . var_dump($form) . '</pre>';  
$html = '<input type="hidden" name="' . $name . '" value="' . $form->name() . '" />';
```

return $html;
}

No entanto existe um problema pois apenas vai buscar o titulo que é dado no backoffice, se eu alterar o titulo no shortcut [contact-form-7 id="86" title="**Titulo do Shortcut**"] envia me na mesma o titulo do backoffice.

Existe alguma maneira de ir buscar o titulo que inseri no shortcut?

Obrigado

Comment: Pode tentar https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7-modules/ ... Pela a documentação consegue adcionar hidden fields

Comment: Miguel obrigado, mas não me permite adicionar o nome do formulário, o objetivo era usar o mesmo formulário, por exemplo com o id 86, mas alterar o titulo, assim não necessitava de criar um formulário de contacto para cada item, ou seja adicionava o shortcut alterava o titulo e assim sabia a que item aquele contacto se referia

Comment: O plugin Contact Forms utiliza o o atributo `title` para buscar o formulário se o atributo `id` não for fornecido. Se o atributo `id` for fornecido e for um formulário válido, o atributo `title` é ignorado.